# Using Element's tool tip as Locator in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: extjs, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Can we use button's **tool tip** as a **locator** in selenium WebDriver? I came across this question because none of the default locators provided in selenium webdriver are useful for my applications elements.

Elements in the application i am testing **randomly** changes its,
**Id, 
Xpath-pos, 
Xpath-relative Id, and
CSS**
everytime the page is **Refreshed**! This happens because the application is created in **ExtJs** and **HTML 5**.

Comment: `<button id="button-1103-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" data-qtip="Add Request" style="height: 14px;">`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. But please show your HTML code. There are no general answers.

For example, this ExtJS demo here. http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/demos/Ext.Button.tooltip.1/

```
<button id="button-1009-btnEl" type="button" class="x-btn-center" hidefocus="true" role="button" autocomplete="off" data-qtip="I'm a custom tooltip" style="height: 16px;">
     <span id="button-1009-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="">Button w/ QuickTip (qtip) tooltip</span>
     <span id="button-1009-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon "></span>
</button>
```

The tooltip is coded as `data-qtip` attribute. So you can use CSS Selector or XPath to find it.

XPath: `//button[@data-qtip=\"I'm a custom tooltip\"]`

CSS: `button[data-qtip=\"I'm a custom tooltip\"]`

Comment: `<button id="button-1103-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" data-qtip="Add Request" style="height: 14px;">`

Answer (score 1):

Good question !

I would like to discuss it with some more experts but as far as my knowledge goes **i dont think** u can use tool tips as locators in webdriver!

Try this flow, may help you

1. don't bother if your script fails in IDE
2. Export it in webdriver/java/Junit
3. Try running the webdriver script now.

Comment: Sorry but this dosent work with locator = id OR Xpath

Answer (score 0):

If the tooltip is in the HTML (which it must be), then you'll be able to use an XPath selector to find your element. Post a snippet of the HTML with the element you're trying to locate for more help

Comment: <button id="button-1103-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" data-qtip="Add Request" style="height: 14px;">